# Is it possible to use JUNG/Graphviz Layout-/Arrange-functions within a GEF / GMF Project?

Tags: java, graphviz, jung, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I want to build an graphical editor that draws and modifies graphs. The GEF-given "Auto-Arrange"-function is kind of too simple and not customizable. Is it possible to get JUNG/Graphviz auto-layouting and/or -arranging functions into my GEF editor?

Comment: I can now fully recommend JGraphX for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding JUNG, there is no problem, but you would have to implement the following code:

1. A GEF action that calls the layout algorithm.
2. Transformation of your model to the model used by JUNG.
3. Reading the results of the layout algorithm from JUNG and changing your model (using commands, of course).